# only last radio button triggers checkCBfont() function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a group of radio buttons and two text fields. When a radio button is checked, its label and only its label is supposed to turn bold. However only the last one executes the onclick event, and this turns all the other labels bold in addition to its own, which it should not do. The other radio buttons do nothing when checked.

This is my form, which is in the body of the html document:

```
<form name="form1">
From Date: <input type=text name="FromDate" id="FromDate" value="" maxlength=10 size=12 autocomplete="off" onFocus="this.select();" onblur="CheckDate(this)">
<br>
To Date: <input type=text name="ToDate" id="ToDate" value="" maxlength=10 size=12 autocomplete="off" onFocus="this.select()" onblur="CheckDate(this)">
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="dvval" value="">
<br>
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="dateview" id="dvlist" value="list" checked onclick="checkCBfont();">List
<br>
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="dateview" id="dvcal" value="calendar" onclick="checkCBfont();">Calendar 
<br>
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="dateview" id="dvgantt" value="gantt" onclick="checkCBfont();">Gantt
<br>
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="dateview" id="dvds" value="dailyswitching" onclick="checkCBfont();">Daily Switching
<br>
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="dateview" id="dvdd" value="dailydetail" onclick="checkCBfont();">Daily Detail
<br>
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="dateview" id="dvcd" value="currentdetail" onclick="checkCBfont();">Current/Future Detail
<br>
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="dateview" id="dvco" value="currentonly" onclick="checkCBfont();">Current/Future List 
<br>
</form>
```

and these are the functions that are supposed to respond to the onclick event, which are in separate sets of script tags in the head of the html document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkCBfont() {
   var ckBx=document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');    // -- get all the input elements in the document
   var t='';
   for (i=0; i < ckBx.length;i++) {
      t=ckBx[i].getAttribute('type');
      if(t!=null){t=t.toLowerCase();}
      if (t=='checkbox'||t=='radio') { // -- get only those inputs that are checkboxes or radio buttons
         togglefont(ckBx[i]);          // -- if they're checked, make them bold, else make them normal
      }
   }     
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function togglefont(cb)  {
   //...toggle the label on a checkbox from bold to not-bold and back, when checked...
   if (cb.checked==true || cb.checked) {
       cb.parentNode.style.fontWeight='bold'; 
   }else{
       cb.parentNode.style.fontWeight='normal'; 
   }
} 
</script>
```

I have tried several different approaches, including but not limited to using inspect element, try...catch, and google, but I cannot seem to locate the problem.

To reiterate, the problem is that the last radio button bolds all the labels in lieu of each radio button only bolding its own label when clicked/checked.

Can anyone offer any advice and/or suggestions?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: To make the onclick event checkCBfont() execute for all the radio buttons whenever they are clicked and bold whichever one is clicked, instead of the event only firing for the very last one on the list and bolding them all

Answer (score 1):

The parent element of your radio inputs is the <form>-tag. Therefore, if you change the font weight of the parent element, all labels are changed. You have to include all labels inside another element, e.g.:

```
<form name="form1">
From Date: <input type="text" name="FromDate" id="FromDate" value="" maxlength=10 size=12 autocomplete="off" onFocus="this.select();" onblur="CheckDate(this)">
<br>
To Date: <input type="text" name="ToDate" id="ToDate" value="" maxlength=10 size=12 autocomplete="off" onFocus="this.select()" onblur="CheckDate(this)">
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="dvval" value="">
<br>
<span><input type="radio" class="radio" name="dateview" id="dvlist" value="list" checked onclick="checkCBfont();">List</span>
<br>
<span><input type="radio" class="radio" name="dateview" id="dvcal" value="calendar" onclick="checkCBfont();">Calendar </span>
<br>
<span><input type="radio" class="radio" name="dateview" id="dvgantt" value="gantt" onclick="checkCBfont();">Gantt</span>
<br>
<span><input type="radio" class="radio" name="dateview" id="dvds" value="dailyswitching" onclick="checkCBfont();">Daily Switching</span>
<br>
<span><input type="radio" class="radio" name="dateview" id="dvdd" value="dailydetail" onclick="checkCBfont();">Daily Detail</span>
<br>
<span><input type="radio" class="radio" name="dateview" id="dvcd" value="currentdetail" onclick="checkCBfont();">Current/Future Detail</span>
<br>
<span><input type="radio" class="radio" name="dateview" id="dvco" value="currentonly" onclick="checkCBfont();">Current/Future List </span>
<br>
</form>
```

The JavaScript part worked for me without problems.

Example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/h66sn0a3/)

Comment: Alright that worked, not sure if it would have occurred to me to use span otherwise. I assumed it was a problem with the function itself. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with JQuery with a lot less code: https://jsfiddle.net/ezj1Lfbw/10/

HTML

```
<form name="form1">
  From Date:
  <input type="text" name="FromDate" id="FromDate" value="" maxlength=10 size=12 autocomplete="off" onFocus="this.select();" onblur="CheckDate(this)">
  <br> To Date:
  <input type="text" name="ToDate" id="ToDate" value="" maxlength=10 size=12 autocomplete="off" onFocus="this.select()" onblur="CheckDate(this)">
  <br>
  <input type="hidden" name="dvval" value="">
  <br>
  <span><input type="radio" class="radio" name="dateview" id="dvlist" value="list" checked>List</span>
  <br>
  <span><input type="radio" class="radio" name="dateview" id="dvcal" value="calendar">Calendar </span>
  <br>
  <span><input type="radio" class="radio" name="dateview" id="dvgantt" value="gantt">Gantt</span>
  <br>
  <span><input type="radio" class="radio" name="dateview" id="dvds" value="dailyswitching">Daily Switching</span>
  <br>
  <span><input type="radio" class="radio" name="dateview" id="dvdd" value="dailydetail">Daily Detail</span>
  <br>
  <span><input type="radio" class="radio" name="dateview" id="dvcd" value="currentdetail">Current/Future Detail</span>
  <br>
  <span><input type="radio" class="radio" name="dateview" id="dvco" value="currentonly">Current/Future List </span>
  <br>
</form>
```

JQuery

```
  $('span').click(function() {
    $('span').removeClass('bold')
    $(this).addClass('bold')
  })
```

CSS

```
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will remember this as well